# Datatables PDF Export Incomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have a simple html table. The pagination is off so all 50 rows or so display on the page. The excel export works great. The PDF export only displays 1 page which is about one third of the content. Is there a simple way of exporting all rows? Even with the pagination set to true, the export is still incomplete. After doing some research, what I have should be working. I just can't figure out why its failing and exporting only one page.

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function() {
$('#summary_table').DataTable( {
    dom: 'Bfrtip',
    buttons: [
        'excelHtml5',
                    {
            extend: 'pdfHtml5',
            orientation: 'landscape',
            pageSize:'LEGAL'
        }
    ],
paging:false

} );
  } );

</script>
```

The html has this structure

```
<table class="display">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
    </tr> 
    .
    .
    .
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the datatables site has examples with the below pdfmake CDN's

```
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/bpampuch/pdfmake/0.1.27/build/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/bpampuch/pdfmake/0.1.27/build/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
```

I removed the above from my code and replaced with 0.1.32 version through cdnjs instead. PDF button produced a full export of all pages now!

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.32/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.32/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about your included js and css. You can try this. Here is a [working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/codebazz/ebRXw/3288/)

```
<table id="example" class="display nowrap" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Position</th>
          <th>Office</th>
          <th>Age</th>
          <th>Start date</th>
          <th>Salary</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>

      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
          <td>System Architect</td>
          <td>Edinburgh</td>
          <td>61</td>
          <td>2011/04/25</td>
          <td>$320,800</td>
        </tr>

      </tbody>
</table>
```

```html
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        dom: 'Bfrtip',
        buttons: [
            'copyHtml5',
            'excelHtml5',
            'csvHtml5',
            'pdfHtml5'
        ],
        paging: false
    } );
} );
```

And don't forget to include these files

> https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js
>   https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.4.0/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js 
>   //cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/3.1.3/jszip.min.js
>   //cdn.rawgit.com/bpampuch/pdfmake/0.1.27/build/pdfmake.min.js
>   //cdn.rawgit.com/bpampuch/pdfmake/0.1.27/build/vfs_fonts.js
>   //cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.4.0/js/buttons.html5.min.js
>   https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css
>   https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.4.0/css/buttons.dataTables.min.css

Comment: confirmed, on all that. I am pretty much giving up on this. Maybe its my browser version that is the issue. I will have to live with Excel working.

Answer (score -1):

Set Page Setting before Export .

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {       
            WebClient wc = new WebClient();
            string url = Request.Url.AbsoluteUri;
            string fileContent = wc.DownloadString(url); 
            List<string> tableContents = GetContents(fileContent, table_pattern);
            string HTMLString = String.Join(" ", tableContents.ToArray());   
            Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 10f, 10f, 10f, 0f);
            PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, Response.OutputStream);             
            pdfDoc.Open();
            pdfDoc.Add(new Paragraph("Welcome to dotnetfox"));
            List<IElement> htmlarraylist = HTMLWorker.ParseToList(new StringReader(HTMLString), null);
            for (int k = 0; k < htmlarraylist.Count; k++)
            {
                pdfDoc.Add((IElement)htmlarraylist[k]);
            } 
            pdfDoc.Close();
            Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;" +
                                           "filename=sample.pdf");
            Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
            Response.Write(pdfDoc);
            Response.End();       
        }   
    }
```